# Change all buttons on a form

Tags: c#, winforms, button, controls

I have come very close to finding a solution to this one; just missing one minor detail at this point.

What I am trying to do:
I want to change the cursor style of every button on my Form (Form1) through code. I know how to search through all controls on my form using *foreach*, but I'm not sure how to pass this control as a parameter through the routine that I wrote. I will show an example of what I am doing below.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Button b in this.Controls)
    {
        ChangeCursor(b);  // Here is where I'm trying to pass the button as a parameter.  Clearly this is not acceptable.
    }     
}

private void ChangeCursor(System.Windows.Forms.Button Btn)
{
    Btn.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
}
```

Might anyone have a tip for me?

Thank you very much

Evan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only thing I see is that if you have nested controls, this.Controls will not pick those up. you can try this

```
public IEnumerable<Control> GetSelfAndChildrenRecursive(Control parent)
{
    List<Control> controls = new List<Control>();

    foreach(Control child in parent.Controls)
    {
        controls.AddRange(GetSelfAndChildrenRecursive(child));
    }

    controls.Add(parent);

    return controls;
}
```

and call

```
GetSelfAndChildrenRecursive(this).OfType<Button>.ToList()
                  .ForEach( b => b.Cursor = Cursors.Hand);
```

Comment: I'd suggest that making `GetSelfAndChildrenRecursive` as a Generic method and filter the controls by a specific type like: `GetSelfAndChildrenRecursive<Button>()` instead of get all types then filter them by a specific type

Comment: @Homam I use this function for other purposes where I might want to operate on contorls of diff type (like enable all nested controls). But for the OP's purposes, what you suggest might work but still OfType<> is very readable.

Comment: @Homam I think I might have gotten close to what you were thinking with my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/42400534/1039753.

Comment: I think `.OfType<Button>()` is correct not `.OfType<Button>` according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44983056/4439444

Answer (score 7):

Change

```
foreach (Button b in this.Controls)
{
    ChangeCursor(b);  // Here is where I'm trying to pass the button as a parameter.
                      // Clearly this is not acceptable.
}
```

to

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
   if (c is Button)
   {
        ChangeCursor((Button)c);  
   }
}
```

Not every control on a form is a button.

Edit: You should also look for nested controls. See Bala R. answer.

Comment: Also, not every control on a form is a direct child of the form.  This approach doesn't include children of children.

Comment: I FOUND THE ISSUE: This is only searching my TAB CONTROL ! not my form!

Answer (score 2):

Same principle as Bala R's answer but the way I do it is...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AppName
{
    public static class ControlExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAllCtls(this Control control, Type type)
        {
            var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();

            return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAllCtls(ctrl, type))
                                      .Concat(controls)
                                      .Where(c => c.GetType() == type);
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like this...

```
foreach (Control ctl in this.GetAllCtls(typeof(Button)))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Found a button on the form called '" + ctl.Text + "'");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That looks correct to me; is there a problem I'm not seeing?

EDIT:  Ahh yes - if you have non-button controls in the collection, the cast will fail.

You want to only pass in controls that *are* buttons, so you'll want to add an IF statement.

Comment: Yeah, Visual Studio in debug mode highlights "button b" and says - "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.TabControl' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'."

Comment: Not quite correct, controls on a form can be more than just buttons.

Comment: -1: It will only be correct if the `Form` only contains `Button` controls.

Comment: The question was, 'but I'm not sure how to pass this control as a parameter through the routine that I wrote'.  His code did *that* successfully.  Yes, non-button controls could cause a runtime error, but that wasn't part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

If any of your controls fail to inherit from button I think your foreach will throw an exception.

try something like this:

```
foreach (Control b in this.Controls)
{

  if (b is Button)
    ChangeCursor((Button)b);  
}
```

Comment: Russel - While your above code does throw any exceptions, it does not alter any button on the form.  It does not get past "if (b is button)" at any point on the loop.

Comment: I'll have to believe you Evan as I haven't compiled it but I can't see why that would be the case.

Comment: As an aside - it's always better to wrap foreach/if etc blocks in curly braces even if there is only one line as it will save on programming errors at a later date - I was just being lazy. Should still work though.

Comment: @Evan. If one of those controls is a Button, then it will most definitely get past the if.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use for a bit cleaner syntax:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)    
{       
    if (c is Button)       
    {          
        ChangeCursor(c as Button);         
    }    
}
```