# Making A Foreach loop for all of my Labels In C#

Tags: c#, foreach, label, background-color

I'm trying to make all my label's Background Color Black but if I did it will look like this:

```
lable0.BackColor = Color.Black;
lable1.BackColor = Color.Black;
```

108 More Times. So I want to know if there is a way to use a foreach loop like:

```
int[] labels = new int[] {1, 2, 3...110};
foreach (int i in labels)
{
      label.BackColor = Color.Black;
}
```

Comment: Can you simply make an array of labels and then use a foreach loop to cycle through those?

Comment: What is the background color of your form?

Comment: Control is my form background color

Comment: You could use string concatenation to get them like this: `this.Controls["label" + i]`. You'd have to cast it to a `Label` of course. Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5794699/945456

Comment: @hus274 How would he do that is the question, without having 110 Add statements?

Answer (score 6):

This should work for you, if your labels are direct child of your form (I assume this is winforms) :

```
foreach(Label lbl in this.Controls.OfType<Label>())
{ 
   lbl.BackColor = Color.Black;
}
```

Comment: `+1`, this of course assumes you want to change every Label on the form, and not just a specific set of them.

Comment: Easily modifiable to only apply `BackColor` to specific `Label`s if necessary.

Comment: @MikeChristensen wow, is there more of them (more than 108) ? :p

Comment: @Jblayone It's not working tell us nothing.. have you added `using System.Linq;` directive ?

Answer (score 0):

Winforms controls are hierarchical, so you need to walk them recursively to find all the labels:

```
    public static IEnumerable<Control> WalkControls(this Control topControl)
    {
        if (topControl == null)
            yield break;
        yield return topControl;
        foreach (var child in topControl.Controls.OfType<Control>())
            foreach (var subChild in WalkControls(child))
                yield return subChild;
    }

    public static void SetControlTreeBackColor<TControl>(Control topControl, Color color) where TControl : Control
    {
        foreach (var childControl in topControl.WalkControls().OfType<TControl>())
            childControl.BackColor = color;
    }
```

Here you would use "Label" for "TControl".