# How to change property of all buttons in windows from?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, visual-studio-2013

I have some buttons on `Form1`. I want to set their `FlatStyle` property to `FlatStyle.Popup`.
I searched and wrote some code as below:

```
// List<Control> ButtonsList = new List<Control>();
 List<Button> ButtonsList = new List<Button>();
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Icon = Properties.Resources.autorun;  //Project->Properties->Resources->
            ButtonsList = GetAccessToAllButtons(this).OfType<Button>.ToList(); //*** hot line ***

            foreach(Button btn in ButtonList)
            {
                btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup;
            }

        }



 public IEnumerable<Control> GetAccessToAllButtons(Control thisClass)
        {
            List<Control> ControlsList = new List<Control>();
            foreach (Control child in thisClass.Controls)
            {
                ControlsList.AddRange(GetAccessToAllButtons(child));
            }
            ControlsList.Add(thisClass);
            return ControlsList;
        }
```

But when I use `GetAccessToAllButtons()` in hot line of my code, VS generates this error:

> 'System.Linq.Queryable.OfType(Query.Linq.IQueryable)' is a
>   'method', which is not valid in the given context

What is my mistake?

**Edit:** My reference at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5794767/4439444) missed the `()`. It is an accepted answer! Do we have a different situation at my reference? or it is only a typo?

Comment: How many buttons do you have? If it is 10 or 20, you can create a array that holds the references to the button variable instead of writing a recursion? For e.g. `var buttons = new Button[] {button1, button2, button3 }` Or are you adding buttons to form dynamically?

Comment: @shahkalpesh I have 14 buttons and add them at loading of the form NOT dynamically.

Comment: While you have got the answer, it will be ok to have 14 variable names added to a button array instead of trying to find button at runtime, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OfType` is Generic Method and you must use it as a method.
Just replace that line to the following:

```
ButtonsList = GetAccessToAllButtons(this).OfType<Button>().ToList();
```

Also I will recommend you to write method as below:

```
public List<Button> GetAllButtons(Form f)
{
    List<Button> resultList = new List<Button>();
    foreach(Control a in f.Controls)
    {
        if(a is Button)
        {
            resultList.Add((Button)a);
        }
    }
    return resultList;
}
```

and use it in this way :

```
var myBtns = GetAllButtons(yourForm);
foreach (var btn in myBtns)
{
    btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> .OfType<Button>
> ```

`OfType` is a method so you are are missing the `()` at the end of it. It should be:

```
.OfType<Button>()
```

Answer (score 1):

U need to call like this : `OfType<Button>().ToList();`

Below link will help u understand the OfType Method:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx

Better to use this way:

```
foreach (var control in this.Controls)
{
   if (control.GetType()== typeof(Button))
   {
       //do stuff with control in form
   }
}
```

Comment: Very Useful Answer. Thanks.