# Calling upon multiple labels at once

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

So far I have managed to get the code working how I want it to for Label 1. I have 23 labels that need to have the same code attached to them. I'm having trouble trying to come up with a faster, more efficient way of doing this as I am quite new to VB. 
Any Help would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub HitMazeWall()

    'Hitting the right side of the wall
    If Label1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(PictureBox1.Bounds) And PictureBox1.Bounds.Left < Label1.Bounds.Right And PictureBox1.Bounds.Right > Label1.Bounds.Right Then
        PictureBox1.Left += 5

        'Hitting the left side of the wall
    ElseIf Label1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(PictureBox1.Bounds) And PictureBox1.Bounds.Right > Label1.Bounds.Left And PictureBox1.Bounds.Left < Label1.Bounds.Left Then
        PictureBox1.Left -= 5

        'Hitting the top side of the wall
    ElseIf Label1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(PictureBox1.Bounds) And PictureBox1.Bounds.Top < Label1.Bounds.Bottom And PictureBox1.Bounds.Bottom > Label1.Bounds.Bottom Then
        PictureBox1.Top += 5

        'Hitting the bottom side of the wall
    ElseIf Label1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(PictureBox1.Bounds) And PictureBox1.Bounds.Bottom > Label1.Bounds.Top And PictureBox1.Bounds.Top < Label1.Bounds.Top Then
        PictureBox1.Top -= 5

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Label1` is an object reference.  If that was a method you could call it with whichever other label reference you wanted; then you could further refine it by looping on all the labels.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about `For each....Next` statement?If not, then take a look at [this](https://www.dotnetperls.com/for-each-vbnet)
In your case,a simple `For each` statement would do the job.The code would look like :

```
 For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf c Is Label Then
        'Your code here
    End If
```

Here,the code checks the form for the controls.Now, in a form, there are many controls and not all are labels,so the application need to figure out what type of control u r targetting.So, we use `TypeOf`.I guess the rest of the code doesn't need any explanation .

For more info,visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794699/change-all-buttons-on-a-form)